# repeticion de datos en webscraping usando xpath

Tags: html, web, scraping, google-chrome, xpath

tengo un problema estoy intentado scrapear datos de una pagina y al buscar tal dato, este se repite muchas veces y nose por donde va el problema
Aqui les dejo el codigo

`$x('//div[@class="cs"]/div/text()').map(x=>x.wholeText)`

Lo que me arroja lo siguiente
(['CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)'....................'CS 241 (7.5)', 'CS 241 (7.5)', 'CS 241 (7.5)', 'CS 226 (9.2)', 'CS 226 (9.2)', …]

Solo quiero que me arroje una vez ''CS 35 (1.4)'' y luego me arroje el siguiente dato 'CS 269 (7.3)' y asi... no lo quiero repetido 7 veces en secuencia

La pagina que estoy scrapeando es https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush

Comment: deberias colocar un ejemplo minimo. ni siquiera mencionaste el lenguaje.

Comment: Nose si llamarlo lenguaje, solo le hago scraping a una pagina web usando xpath para que me arroje datos, el ejemplo es el que puse arriba, coloco ese codigo en la consola de chrome y me arroja eso

Comment: si es desde la consola solo has $x('//div[@class="cs"]/div[1]/text()')[1]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, probe tu codigo y no me entrega lo que ando buscando, quiero que me entregue todos los datos que busco en la consola del navegador, solo que no quiero que se repita 7 veces el mismo numero y de ahi pase al siguiente, quiero que solo me lo entregue 1 vez y pase al siguiente, nose si se me entiende

Comment: let xpathResult = document.evaluate('//div[@class="cs"]/div/text()', document);
let values = [];
let node = xpathResult.iterateNext();
while (node) {
    values.push(node.wholeText);
    node = xpathResult.iterateNext();
}
let uniqueValues = [...new Set(values)];
console.log(uniqueValues);

Comment: solo pegalo en la consola

Comment: gracias ese me funciono!